# Switch off java.langObject initialization in podam

Tags: java, jaxb, jemos-podam

I have POJOs:

```
class PersonJob {

private PersonAddress address;

//a buch of fields (non Object type)
}

class PersonAddress extends AbstractContact {
//empty fields class
}

class AbstractContact {
    private Object contactId;

    public Object getContactId() { return this.contactId }

    public void setContactId(Object contactId) {this.contactId = contactId}
}
```

AbstractContact class is placed in external library.

I'm using PodamFactory with my DataProvider which extending AsbractRandomDataProviderStrategy for filling PersonJob. But when JAXB serializes it I git such error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object incompatible with org.w3c.dom.Element
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.AnyTypeBeanInfo.serializeURIs(AnyTypeBeanInfo.java:153)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:677)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:341)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
                at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
                at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:128)
                at ru.sbrf.bh.banking.product.pcard.branchpcard.orchestration.ValidatePersonProcess.marshallObject(ValidatePersonProcess.java:76)
                at ru.sbrf.bh.banking.product.pcard.branchpcard.orchestration.ValidatePersonProcess.validatePerson(ValidatePersonProcess.java:60)
                at ru.sbrf.bh.banking.product.pcard.branchpcard.service.flow.card.PersonValidationTest.testFilledValidation(PersonValidationTest.java:74)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
                at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
                at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
                at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
                at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
                at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
                at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
                at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
                at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:122)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Is there a way to switch off instantiation of contactId field for AbstractContact class through DataProvider which extending AsbractRandomDataProviderStrategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, can you change `contactId` to an actual type? I bet during runtime it's not an `Object`, but as it's declared it confuses Podam.

If the former is not an option, then you can do three things:

1. Exclude `contactId` field with `@PodamExclude` annotation
2. Exclude `contactId` field with a class info strategy

   DefaultClassInfoStrategy classInfoStrategy = DefaultClassInfoStrategy.getInstance();
   classInfoStrategy.addExcludedField(PersonAddress.class, "contactId");
   podamFactory.setClassStrategy(classInfoStrategy);
3. Simply call `pojo.setContactId(null);` after manufacturing or even better `pojo.setContactId(yourActualAddressObject);`

Comment: The second variant turned up to be the most convenient solution in my case as I cannot modify the POJO from external library. Thaks for your answer!